# PHP JAVA bridge on wamp server

Tags: java, php, architecture, lamp

We would like to proof of concept for given below situation.

We have php based app with most of our business logic, important algorithms in the form of classes, so when we deploy our offering to enterprises what we are thinking was to compile the core php classes into Java objects or JAR.

I tried to configure php/java bridge but  no luck on my desktop using wamp server.

Can any one help me out ? php 5.3.8

Comment: It sounds like a wild idea, however, StackOverflow is for specific programming questions. I'd suggest you tell us, what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Florian I guess he has tried the ones in the pre-last paragraph

Comment: I know stackoverflow was specific to prgm questions, I have already told that I have configured hhvm and run our app

Comment: What i meant was using code examples to show us, what you've tried.